# javascript problems with window refreshing

Tags: javascript

```
var newdiv, parent = $("#tuples");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    parent.append("<div></div>");
    newdiv=parent.children().eq(index+i); 
    newdiv.css("display", "inline");
    newdiv.css("float", "left");

    newdiv.css("width", width + "px");
    newdiv.css("margin-right", "5px");
    newdiv.css("margin-left", "5px");
} 

child = parent.children();

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    newdiv = child.eq(i + index); 
    x.appendTo(newdiv);
    x = x.clone(); // here x is the whole node inside each new div
} 

//here change the attributes and images in the new divs
for (i = 0 + index; i < (10 + index); i++)
    child[i].setAttribute("index", i.toString());
```

The code is running well except that the new divs added are being shown below the parent for about quarter of  a second and then the browser is resetting them horizontally that is looking weird, since it looks like the window is flickering. However if I give an alert after adding divs and then press ok to that alert ,then the attributes in the new divs are changed without any flicker; In this case, the divs are added directly horizontally (not vertically in the first place)

I thought lets give a delay after adding the divs and then change attributes but that didn't solve the problem. I think browser is not updating the window or flushing just after the adding the divs. Is there any method to flush the added contents to the html?

Comment: It'd be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she did so?

Comment: the downvoter is complicating my problems instead of solving them. :/